# Symfony Twig Template: string comparison first converting to lower case

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following code for PHP

```
$option = "yes";
```

and Twig tag

```
{% if option == "yes" %}
```

it works fine, but it fails if capitalized

```
$option = "YES";
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
{% if option == "yes" | lower %}
```

Any other way? Can't seems to find this from the Twig documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{% if option == "yes" | lower %}
```

is the same as `{% if option == "yes" %}`, because you are converting the string "yes" to lowercase, which it already is. You want to convert the variable to lowercase instead and then compare them:

```
{% if option|lower == "yes" %}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `"mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"` error. @Paulpro do you know a solution for `{% if (Link.Type)|lower == "workshop" %}`

Comment: @Jörn I guess `Link.Type` isn't a string. If you're in debug mode in Symfony, you can do `{{ dump( Link.Type ) }}` to determine what it is.